# How I initialize a pointer address in C when the address value is known?

Tags: c

In C language:

I want to create output file by, `f = fopen("Hanoi_Output","w");` `f` is my pointer to the file Hanoi_Output opening in write mood.The file is creating in the location where my source code,i.e. my .c file is.
  But, I want the output file in other location,that I will pre-define. How I'll do this?

Comment: Pass a different path when opening? How is that supposed to be related to pointers? And how is that a problem?

Comment: I'd suggest renaming your question, perhaps `How to create a file in a directory other than the current one` is a better name? I'd also hazard a bet that theres already a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I want this file to my desired location not where my source code is. But,by default, the address denoted by 'f' is of that location,where my source code is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct a string which represents the path to your file, then pass that string to `fopen`.

If both the path and the filename are fixed, just use a string literal with the path:

```
f = fopen("/path/to/file/Hanoi_Output","w");
```

If the directory is contained in some other string, then you can use `snprintf` to build it:

```
char path[500];
snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/Hanoi_Output", dir_name);
f = fopen(path,"w");
```

Comment: Please explain the path, and corresponding string logic.

Comment: Note: `- 1` not needed in `snprintf(path, sizeof(path)-1,...`

Comment: Or `#include <limits.h> ... char path[PATH_MAX] = "";`  `:)`

Comment: Aside: Using `snprintf()` is not "better" than `sprintf()` here.  Overflow is bad - yes, yet creating a file with the wrong name is also bad.  Better to use `snprintf()` _and_ check its return value before proceeding to `fopen()`.

Comment: @Nabendu, this is a *Pick your favorite tutorial* issue. `char path[500];` is simply an uninitialized character array of `500` chars to allow you to *concatenate* the actual *directory path* (including a directory separator) and the *filename* so that when `path` is passed to `fopen`, it creates the file in *your chosen directory* (e.g. in the *directory* you pass as `dir_name` to `snprintf`) instead of in the *Present Working Directory*.

Comment: Thanks.... It's Working